Auth0 Using Cognito as an OIDC Provider
I am attempting to configure an enterprise connection from Auth0 to AWS Cognito to use the Cognito User Pool as a OIDC provider for Auth0. I am following this documentation from Auth0: https://auth0.com/docs/authenticate/identity-providers/enterprise-identity-providers/oidc
After filling out the form with the Issuer URL and Client ID and clicking create I am presented with the following error:

Error!
Something happened while trying to create your connection: "options.issuer" is required

I have also attached a screenshot with the page and the error present.

Note - this is not setting up Auth0 as IdP for Cognito, but allowing Auth0 to connect to Cognito via OIDC to retrieve user information.
I have looked through all of the Auth0 documentation regarding setting up this connection. I have reviewed my settings in Cognito and all available scopes are selected.
The openid-configuration can be seen here: https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_YTTtleCKb/.well-known/openid-configuration and issuer is present.
I would expect after filling in the information to Auth0 and clicking Create the connection to Cognito would be created.

I encountered the same issue. I wasn't able to get it to work through the UI.
However the "Create a connection" Management API worked  (https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2/connections/post-connections).
In particular, I used the approach of specifying the URLs explicitly.
So I used a request body similar to this one:
{
    "strategy": "oidc",
    "name": "my-oidc",
    "display_name": "My OID",
    "options": {
        "type": "back_channel",
        "issuer": "{ISSUER_URL}/",
        "authorization_endpoint": "{ISSUER_URL}/authorize",
        "token_endpoint": "{ISSUER_URL}/token",
        "jwks_uri": "{ISSUER_URL}/jwk",
        "client_id": "{CLIENT_ID}",
        "client_secret": "{CLIENT_SECRET}",
        "scopes": "openid profile"
    }
}

where {ISSUER_URL}, {CLIENT_ID}, {CLIENT_SECRET} were values that I replaced.
